# requestAnimationFrame syncing issue in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

When running an animation through canvas, I notice that Safari 7 in Mavericks actually seems to get out of sync with the screen randomly. I'm certain its not random, nothing with a computer really is, so I'm hoping to gain some insight to whats really going on here. I assume it's a refresh syncing issue because it claims to run at a cool 60fps even when it acts all jerky.

The code that calls the main loop :

```
Studio.render = function(){
    Studio.tick();
    Studio.stage.render();
    requestAnimationFrame(Studio.render);
}
```

Studio.tick:

```
Studio.tick = function() {
    this._now       = Studio.now();
    this.delta      = this._now - this.time;
    this.time       = this._now;
    this.frameRatio = this.delta/16.666666666666668; // vs 60fps
};
```

Studio.now: ... im using a performance.now shim, so for Safari its equates to

```
Date.now
```

I had figured early on that it was going to be a memory issue, the garbage collector was kicking in and that was causing the random stuttering. Removed as much of that as possible, and the issue persists.

I then went ahead and swapped out the definition for requestAnimationFrame `window.requestAnimationFrame = window.setTimeout;` causing Safari to use a timeout instead, I added in a duration of 16 to the main Studio.render `requestAnimationFrame(Studio.render,16);` Things seemed to get a little better. Puzzled by this I changed it to `requestAnimationFrame(Studio.render,4);` and all of a sudden it was silky smooth. Clearly it's not a memory issue, running all the computations 4x should have resulted in 4x as many pauses.

I hope I'm missing something obvious, otherwise when playing through Safari I'll have to resort to a setTimeout which feels so wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Studio.tick there does probably not you expect it to do.. could you setup a fiddle for us?

Comment: Yeah I'll work on making a simplified demo. Do you see anything about my tick function that stands out as being odd?

Comment: @Ken so I went to make a few demos, and as would be the case... they didn't display the same issue. The game I'm developing is far too big to place on a fiddle. However your comment did cause me to look into the requestAnimationFrame spec, and I noticed it sends back a HighResTimeStamp. Using this helps me 2 fold. I no longer need to shim performance.now since Safari sends back the same thing through a RAF. This seems to be helping prevent the jerky movement in Safari.